# How to restrict browser from going back to external site?

Tags: php, redirect, back-button, usability, user-experience

I'm trying to a find a cross-browser implementation that would work for the following situation.

A user completes one of our online applications and is redirected to an external, online payment system. They enter their banking details and are then redirected back to our application where they're presented with a confirmation message.

Now, if the user presses the browser's back button they're brought back to the external banking site where they can enter their banking details a second time. Usually, the bank will notice a second payment coming through for the same order and will not double-charge them, but occasionally older browsers will let a double-payment go through. I believe we can add some client-side code to the banking details page but can't add any server-side logic.

Is there a standard solution to this problem?

Comment: There is - you don't use the API that uses browser redirects, you use your server to implement the logic of making payment (AKA the API that's harder to implement). If you opt for browser redirect method - you assume the user isn't silly and that they won't press "back" button for no obvious reason. If they do press it, it's not up to you to control that, therefore it's not your responsibility to implement this "do not shoot my own foot" protection.

Comment: If the banking site was implemented properly, it wouldn't be possible to go back to it and issue another money transfer, because some associated transaction token would have expired. Since it's a regular site in the user's browser history, you cannot prevent the user from going back to it.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can perform an additional redirect on your confirmation page, eg at the top:

```
if(!isset($_GET['x'])){
   header("Location: ./?x=x");
   exit();
}
```

then if the user presses back, they will hit the same page, sans the get variable, and be redirected again